# Gradle Task To Call Other Tasks In Order

Tags: continuous-integration, gradle

I'm making a task in gradle that needs to call a number of other tasks.

Here's what I have:

```
task ci(dependsOn: [
    clean,
    build,
    test
])
```

What is strange is the output I see:

```
gradle ci
:compileJava
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:jar
:assemble
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test UP-TO-DATE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:clean             // cleaning after the build
:build
:ci
```

Note, that the clean occurs after the build target, which wipes out my build.

If I change my task to:

```
task ci(dependsOn: [
    clean,
    test
])
```

Then it appears to execute in the correct order:

```
:clean UP-TO-DATE    // cleaning before the build
:compileJava
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test UP-TO-DATE
:ci UP-TO-DATE
```

I tried fixing the original target by adding a build.dependsOn clean, but this seems to have no affect.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It seems I've stumbled upon the issue being debated in [GRADLE-427](http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-427) in which gradle determines the best order to execute the tasks.
I resolved my problem by following the advice therein which is also documented in the [Gradle User Guide - Section 15.5](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html) to establish ordering between disparate tasks.  My final *ci* target thus appears as:

```
task ci(dependsOn: ['clean', 'build', 'uploadArchives'])
build.mustRunAfter clean
uploadArchives.mustRunAfter build
```

And everything now works as expected.

Comment: I've tried this approach in the past, but I don't like it because it introduces artificial dependencies. I've had problems in the past getting the order to be exactly what I need.  I've found that  the "alias" approach outlined elsewhere in this thread works better (and does not introduce artificial dependencies)

Answer (score 9):

**TLDR version:** Here's how I did it in one of my projects (without introducing artificial dependencies).

```
//--- build aliases : define a synonym here if you want a shortcut to run multiple targets

def buildAliases = [
   'all' : ['clean', 'assemble', 'runProvisioner', 'stopTomcat', 'installTomcat', 'deployToTomcat', 'startTomcat'],
   'rebuild' : ['clean', 'assemble']
]
def expandedTaskList = []

gradle.startParameter.taskNames.each {
    expandedTaskList << (buildAliases[it] ? buildAliases[it] : it)
}

gradle.startParameter.taskNames = expandedTaskList.flatten()

println "\n\n\texpanded task list: ${gradle.startParameter.taskNames }\n\n"
```

In order to make use of these aliases, call them as tasks. Examples:

```
./gradlew all
./gradlew rebuild
```

or

```
gradle all
gradle rebuild
```

For further background, see :

https://caffeineinduced.wordpress.com/2015/01/25/run-a-list-of-gradle-tasks-in-specific-order/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Done.  If someone takes the time to come here & explain things (and adjusts the answer based on your feedback), you shouldn't downvote it.  This makes me not want to post here.

Answer (score 4):

I would prefer not to add wrapper task just to make sure an order.

In this case, my solution is as follows -

`run.dependsOn 'clean'
compileJava.mustRunAfter 'clean'`

This makes sure that, `clean` task executes before gradle executes `compileJava`. So effectively, you will create a fresh build all the time.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using some Groovy/Gradle goodness the solution can be further improved with the following:

```
def taskNames = [...] // list of task names

task('lastTask', dependsOn: taskNames)

taskNames.inject(null) { acc, val ->
  if (acc != null) tasks[val].mustRunAfter acc
  tasks[val]
}
```

this way, you can have one place with a list of tasks.